# Cannot connect and create user on self hosted Parse Server in Unity3D

Tags: c#, ios, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I recently deployed Parse Server to Amazon which is working fine when I connect and create users from iOS but doesn't work when I try to connect from Unity3D and there are no logs aswell. Is there any specific setting or something for Unity?? What am I missing? Below is the code for both platforms;

**Unity Code (Not working)**

// Initialization

```
string serverUrl = "http://myserverip.amazonaws.com:80/parse/";
ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration {ApplicationId = "MYAPPID", WindowsKey = "MYCLIENTKEY", Server = serverUrl});
```

// User Creation

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser ();
user.Username = "myname";
user.Password = "mypass";

user.SignUpAsync ().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled){
        Debug.Log("Faliled" + t.IsFaulted);
    }
    else{
        Debug.Log("Success");
        var userId = ParseUser.CurrentUser.ObjectId;
        print (userId);
    }
});
```

**iOS Code (working)**

// Initialization

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration>  _Nonnull configuration) {
    configuration.applicationId = @"MYAPPID";
    configuration.clientKey = @"MYCLIENTKEY";
    configuration.server = @"http://myinstanceIP.amazonaws.com:80/parse";
    configuration.localDatastoreEnabled = YES;
}]];
```

// User Creation

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
user.username = @"my name2";
user.password = @"my pass";
user.email = @"email2@example.com";
[user signUp];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set appID and client key in ParseInitializeBehaviour before calling ParseClient.Initialize. Which is pretty weird because ParseClient.Initialize also takes appID and client key but I got it working this way.

Also add "/" at the end of your server url.

```
ParseInitializeBehaviour _script = new GameObject("ParseInitializeBehaviour").AddComponent<ParseInitializeBehaviour> ();
    _script.applicationID = "APPID";
    _script.dotnetKey = "CLIENTKEY";

ParseClient.Initialize (new ParseClient.Configuration () 
{
    WindowsKey = "APPID",
    ApplicationId = "CLIENTKEY",
    Server = serverUrl
});
```

Everything else i.e signup, signin etc. works normally after this.